# My app is sending me JSON. How do I take that JSON and inject HTML into the page?

Tags: jquery, json

With `$.ajax`, I'm getting a JSON response like follows:

```
[{"project":{"name":"P1111", description":"I like chicken soup","active":true}} .....repeats several times]
```

What I'd like to do with jQuery is take that JSON response, and loop through it to create the following on `id=target`

```
<ul id="target">
  <li>P1111 - I like chicken soup - active</li>
  <li>3311 - I like green soup - active</li>
  <li>4324234 - I like orange soup - active</li>
  <li>123123 - I like hands - active</li>
</ul>
```

My JSON response from the server:

```
[{"project":{"name":"3rd project  XXXX","created_at":"2010-09-21T05:00:28Z","updated_at":"2010-09-21T05:00:28Z","site_id":1,"creator":1,"id":3,"description":"I eat chicken","active":true}},{"project":{"name":"It's 10:11pm2","created_at":"2010-09-21T05:11:25Z","updated_at":"2010-09-21T05:22:07Z","site_id":1,"creator":1,"id":7,"description":"It's 10:11pmIt's 10:11pm22","active":true}},{"project":{"name":"My first project","created_at":"2010-09-21T04:15:54Z","updated_at":"2010-09-21T04:15:54Z","site_id":1,"creator":1,"id":1,"description":"Wowwww","active":true}},{"project":{"name":"What a great project","created_at":"2010-09-21T04:16:07Z","updated_at":"2010-09-21T04:58:24Z","site_id":1,"creator":1,"id":2,"description":"Updated Description2","active":true}},{"project":{"name":"the big 6","created_at":"2010-09-21T05:08:22Z","updated_at":"2010-09-21T05:08:22Z","site_id":1,"creator":1,"id":6,"description":"the big 6the big 6","active":true}}]
```

Comment: Your JSON is not valid, sure you're getting valid input?

Comment: that's just an example... the JSON is good, I promise!

Comment: why getJSON? Any strong reason? thx trying to learn...

Comment: because if you go the way I posted ($.ajax), you send the client more bytes in terms of the # of characters in ur code.

Comment: Got it - thanks all. I ended up using items for each answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using $.ajax

```
$.ajax({
 url: url,
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i,item){
      $('#target').add('<li>' + item.project.name + '</li>');
    });
 }
```

});

I suggest using `$.getJSON` because your code will be shorter, making your transmission to the client smaller.

Thats a rough idea of how to do this. There are many ways of attaching a `li` to the list.

Comment: nice and clean, love that. I just tried that and got an error in Firebug "a is undefined
[Break On This Error] a))();else c.error("Invalid JSON: "+a)...f(d)if(i)for(f in a){if(b.apply(a[f], " But I did check JSONLint and it validated my JSON...

Comment: i edited how you access the json data. Its `item.project.name`

Comment: does it get executed though, and the list gets displayed?

Comment: no it doesn't execute, i tried adding an alert in the EACH with the item.project.name and it errors, same error. Does the JSON look ok to you?

Comment: Maybe it's the data.items, I tried alerting that after success and it says undefined.

Comment: `data` will be the array itself or the complete json response. So there is no data.items. There is `data[0].project.name`

Answer (score 1):

Check out [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) which is a sort of foreach statement. With that you can iterate over your JSON object (any JSON object is actually just a pure JavaScript variable, and in your case it's an array of objects).

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each(data.project, function(i, item) {
     $('#target').append('<li>'+item.name+' - '+item.description+' - '+item.active+'</li>');
});
```

Comment: This will be slow becouse browser will reflow on every item in the array and also data is an array of objects with `project` field, not object with field `project` which is an array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

Just loop over every item using `getJSON`:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data){
    $.each(data, function(i, item){
        var text = item.project.name + ' - ' 
                 + item.project.description + ' - ' 
                 + (item.project.active ? 'active' : 'inactive');
        $('li').html(text).appendTo($('#target'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  $.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(data) {
      var lis = $.map(data, function(elem, i) {
         var project = elem['project'];
         return '<li>' + project['name'] + ' - ' + project['description'] + ' - ' +
                (project['active'] ? 'true' : 'false') + '</li>';
      });
      $('#target').append(lis.join('\n'));
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var _li="";
jQuery.ajax({
 url:'ur_url',
 type:'Get', //or post or jsonp as per need
 success:function(data)
   {
    jQuery.each(data,function(i,item){
       _li=_li+"<li>"+item.project.name +"  -  " +item.project.description +"  -  " +item.project.active+"</li>";
                                   });
   jQuery('#target').html(_li);
   } 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var json = [ {"project":{"name":"P1111", "description":"I like chicken soup","active":true}},
                {"project":{"name":"P2222", "description":"I like chicken soup","active":true}} ];
var html = ['<ul id="target">'];
$.each( json, function(i, p) {
        var a = p.project.active ? "active" : "not active";
        html.push("<li>" + p.project.name + " - " + p.project.description + " - " + a + "</li>");
});
$("body").append(html.join(""));
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this to populate a select (id 'schedule'), that's almost the same scenario you are up to.

$.getJSON("../schedule/" + id, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, value) {
        $("").attr("value", value.id).html(value.name).appendTo("#schedule");
    });
});

Answer (score 0):

I always like to use straight Javascript and put it out to the html document:

```
document.writeln("<ul id='target'>");
for (project in projects ) {
  var active = (project.active) ? "active" : "NOT active";
  document.writeln('<li>'+project.name+' - '+
                          project.description+' - '+active+'</li>');
}
document.writeln("</ul>");
```

Or put it all in a string var and then write it to a div:

```
var htmlStr = "<ul id='target'>";
for (project in projects) {
  var active = (project.active) ? "active" : "NOT active";
  htmlStr += "<li>"+project.name+" - "+project.description+" - "+active+"</li>";
}
htmlStr += "</ul>";
document.getElementById("divTarget").html = htmlStr;
```